# Grails - hide the /index Action using Routes

Tags: grails, routes, url-routing

What it is the correct way to hide the /index action using route in a Grails app?

I want to be able redirect to a controller: "profile", action: "index" but have the url look like
http://foobar.com/profile
not
http://foobar.com/profile/index

Comment: I would like to know also, great question.

Comment: Have you looked at the Grails UrlMapping?

Comment: JIRA: [createLink tag can't create a link without an action](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7827)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UrlMappings.groovy

```
static mappings = {
      "/profile"(controller:"profile", action: "index")
}
```

Or you could set your default action in the Controller

```
class BookController {
    static defaultAction = "index"
}
```

If you are wanting to redirect to that URL then from within an action in a controller..

```
redirect uri: '/profile'  // This one for the UrlMappings solution
```

or

```
redirect controller: 'profile'  // This one for the defaultAction solution.
```

Comment: In Grails 2.2.3, the `defaultAction` workaround unfortunately appends the unwanted `index` to the URL for `<g:link controller="profile">`.  The `mappings` workaround is good and can be shortened to: `"/profile" (controller: "profile")`

Answer (score 3):

```
"/foo/" (controller:"foo", action:"index")
```

This goes in UrlMapping.groovy.
UrlMapping.groovy works both ways, meaning that a g:link to controller foo and action index will also generate that shortened url.

You would need to do this for every controllers index though.

I tried setting:

```
"/$controller" {}
```

But no cigar, maybe someone else knows how this works.

Edit:
Hah, I started writing this answer before you Nick, then spent 10 mins testing out various combinations of just the $controller thingie :-)